# Mysql server burns because of one query, is it possible? How to speed it up?

Tags: mysql

I have noticed, that I am having problem with writing SQL queries, because of the problem with Mysqld, in peak hours. It causes my website to load 3-5 times slower than usually. So I'have tried `siege -d5 -c150 http://mydomain.com/` and looked into `top` and my mysqld takes over 700% of CPU! I've also noticed in mysql status: `Copying to tmp table` and queries adding to some queue or something like this.

```
  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S  %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
25877 mysql     20   0 1076m 227m 8268 S 749.0  2.8 224:02.21 mysqld
```

This is my query

```
SELECT COUNT(downloaded.id) AS downloaded_count
    , downloaded.file_name
    ,uploaded.* 
FROM `downloaded` JOIN uploaded 
ON downloaded.file_name = uploaded.file_name 
WHERE downloaded.completed = '1' 
AND uploaded.active = '1' 
AND uploaded.nsfw = '0' 
AND downloaded.datetime > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) 
GROUP BY downloaded.file_name 
ORDER BY downloaded_count DESC LIMIT 30;
```

Showing rows 0 - 29 ( 30 total, Query took 0.1639 sec) //is this that much? shouldn't it be 0.01s instead?

**UPDATED:** (removed ORDER BY)

Showing rows 0 - 29 ( 30 total, Query took 0.0064 sec)
Why ORDER BY makes it 20x slower?

EXPLAIN

```
+----+-------------+------------+------+---------------+-----------+---------+--------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table      | type | possible_keys | key       | key_len | ref                      | rows | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+------------+------+---------------+-----------+---------+--------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | uploaded   | ALL  | file_name_up  | NULL      | NULL    | NULL                     | 3139 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | downloaded | ref  | file_name     | file_name | 767     | piqik.uploaded.file_name |    8 | Using where                                  |
+----+-------------+------------+------+---------------+-----------+---------+--------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
```

table: uploaded (Total  720.5   KiB)

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `uploaded` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `sid` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `file_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `file_size` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `file_ext` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `file_name_keyword` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `access_key` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `upload_datetime` datetime NOT NULL,
  `last_download` datetime NOT NULL,
  `file_password` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `nsfw` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `votes` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `downloads` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `video_thumbnail` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `video_duration` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `video_resolution` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
  `video_additional` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `active` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `file_name_keyword` (`file_name_keyword`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=3328 ;
```

table: downloaded (Total    5,152.0 KiB)

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `downloaded` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `file_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `completed` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `client_ip_addr` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `client_access_key` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `datetime` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=31475 ;
```

(not sure why I've chosen InnoDB here)

Please note, that I am (still) not using indexes (which as I read is very important!) because of lack of knowledge and I am not sure how to add them correctly.

So the question is, how to improve this query to prevent webserver from slow loading of website? I have only "few" records and can not believe I am having so major problems, people here deal with millions of records and their projects work. How do webhosting companies prevent this problem? (I am hosting only my webpages with over 150 concurrent clients)

Additional info:

Mysql: 5.5.33

Nginx 1.2.1, php5-fpm

Debian 7.1 Wheezy

2x L5420 @ 2.50GHz

8GB RAM

Comment: Please explain, why downvoting and voting for close.

Comment: I'd say that the answer to the question "why is my SELECT so slow?" is "you have no indexes", anyway this is probably a question better suited for dba.stackexchange.com (more knowledgeable audience over there about databases).

Comment: When asking for mysql query optimization, if you look at other questions that ask for the same - you'll notice that either in comments or in answers people ask for output of `EXPLAIN SELECT <your query>`, what engine is being used and what the configuration variables are. Without those, and without knowing what kind of hard disk you're using - it's **impossible** to tell you what you might have done wrong and how to fix it. And that's probably why there's the downvote and close vote.

Comment: I've added explain, hope now its all :)

Comment: Your query returns 3139 rows. After that, it goes through all 3139 rows to order them, after which it discards 3109 rows in order to return 30 rows back (that's how LIMIT works). However, this operation should be cached so if you were to re-run this query a few times, you'll get cached result out. If you want to further improve performance, you should have both engines as InnoDB and larger buffer_pool_size variable so that HDD isn't involved when dealing with this query.

Comment: Thanks for simple explanation. How could I only order last step (30 rows) instead of reordering 3139 rows? So if it is cached, then it should take it from cache and do not perform any calculations on these 3139 rows, but it looks like it does not cache these data and just calculates and orders every query. Is it possible to calculate how much memory it needs to know if it fits in cache? HDD is SAS 15k. I would change table uploaded to InnoDB but there is fulltext key :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few observations:

- You may not have actively chosen InnoDB as a storage engine: it will be the default engine for your version of MySQL. It's probably the right choice for your context, though, as it offers row-level locking instead of table-level locking (amongst other things) which you likely want.
- Don't quote your integers in your comparisons (eg `uploaded.active = '1'`). You'll end up with slower string comparison, instead of integer comparison.
- The comparison `downloaded.datetime > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)` with a derived value is going to be slower than comparison with a normal column value.

Regarding the last point, you could replace this with a user defined variable declared before the query:

```
SET @one_week_ago := DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY);
```

and then within the query compare to that pre-computed value:

```
...
downloaded.datetime > @one_week_ago
...
```

More importantly, though, you'll definitely want to have an index on any key that you're joining on.

In this case, you can add them by:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_file_name ON uploaded(file_name);
CREATE INDEX idx_file_name ON downloaded(file_name);
```

If you don't have indices, you're going to end up with multiple full table scans, which is slow.

There is a cost to adding an index: it takes up space, and it also means writes to the table are slower because the index has to be updated to include them. If this is a query that is running as part of the operation of your website, though, you definitely need the indices.

Comment: Thanks for your post. What do you suggest to use instead of that last step with DATE_SUB(); ?

Comment: I've edited my answer and added a suggestion.